# Can we replace nested sub-queries with joins - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, sqlperformance

Currently we are using the following nested queries to get specific result. The query gives me the correct result, but the problem is that it is taking more time to execute(around 2 seconds to fetch 9 records). Records in the table:

```
Table      |  Number of Records
-------------------------------
Account          284
AccountUser       34
AccountCustomer  256
AccountGroup      96
```

Following is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Account  where (SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX') and  AccountID  IN  
(SELECT AccountID   FROM AccountUser WHERE SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' AND AccountID IN  
(SELECT AccountID   FROM AccountCustomer WHERE SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' AND isDeleted = 0  AND someOtherID IN 
(SELECT someOtherID FROM AccountGroup   WHERE AccountGroupID = 'YYYY-YYYYY-YYYY' AND AccountGroup.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' AND AccountID NOT IN  
(SELECT AccountID   FROM AccountGroup WHERE AccountGroupID = 'YYYY-YYYYY-YYYY' AND AccountGroup.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX'))))
```

I think Joins will give better performance(*correct me if I'm wrong*), hence replaced the nested queries with joins but It doesn't give me the expected result. Joined query like the following:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Account a
Inner join AccountUser b on a.AccountID = b.AccountID
Inner join AccountCustomer c on c.AccountID = a.AccountID 
Inner join AccountGroup d on d.AccountID = a.AccountID 
Inner join AccountGroup e on e.AccountID = a.AccountID 
WHERE a.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and 
      b.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and 
      c.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and 
      c.isDeleted = 0 and d.AccountGroupID = 'YYYY-YYYYY-YYYY' and
      d.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and
      e.AccountGroupID ='YYYY-YYYYY-YYYY'
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the construction of Joins in my query.

Comment: It would greatly help to show some sample data along with your current and expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Sorry Its not possible to share the real data, It would take much time to create these sample data for all tables, Anyway I will make a try.

Comment: One possible difference when you replace a subquery with a join is when you do have a 1-n or n-m relations and the join make the first table rows "duplicate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one out

```
SELECT distinct a.* FROM Account a
Inner join AccountUser b on a.AccountID = b.AccountID
Inner join AccountCustomer c on c.AccountID = a.AccountID 
Inner join AccountGroup d on d.someOtherID = c.someOtherID 
WHERE a.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and 
      b.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and 
      c.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and 
      c.isDeleted = 0 and d.AccountGroupID = 'YYYY-YYYYY-YYYY' and
      d.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' and
      d.AccountID  not in 
(SELECT AccountID   FROM AccountGroup WHERE AccountGroupID = 'YYYY-YYYYY-YYYY' AND AccountGroup.SomeID = 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX')
```

Comment: Fixed my issues when use `distinct a.*` instead for `a.*`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can find.

1. wrong column name

   isDeleted = 0 changes to c.isRelated = 1
2. Wrong Clause for Joining d and e

   AND AccountID NOT IN

Comment: Sorry Bro, `isDeleted` and `isRelated` is by mistake, same result even after changing them

Answer (score 0):

```
Inner join AccountGroup d on d.AccountID = a.AccountID
```

Should be

```
Inner join AccountGroup d on d.someOtherID = a.AccountID
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JOINs you could also look into using WHERE EXISTS or WHERE NOT EXISTS instead of the ugly IN statements. Joins can sometimes return more rows than you would retrieve with the IN statements. From the query I see that you only require the data from the account table so EXISTS seems to be the more logical way to go.

Comment: Can you please come up with an example? I haven't used `WHERE EXISTS` before